# I want to create a set of lists that after some input from the user one will be randomly selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm completely new to all this, I have no clue what I'm doing. I just want an easy selector that asks "What genre are you feeling?" then depending on if the input is rock, rap, indie, or whatever I add in the future spits back a randomly selected album in a list.

```
from random import choice

def lists()
    rock_albums = ['Dark Side of the Moon - Pink Floyd']
    rap_albums = ['Igor - Tyler, the Creator']
    indie_albums = ['Currents - Tame Impala']

print("What genre are you feeling?")
genre = input()

if input("rock"):
    rock = random.choice(albums_rock)
    print(rock)
```

I haven't gone further to add more albums or any other if statements for other genres.

I don't know what else to try. I started with one larger list that could be randomly selected from, that worked, so I advanced. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error. You need a colon after def lists().

Comment: Just replace `if input("rock"):` with `if genre == "rock":`

Comment: Since you're completely new to all of this and have no clue what you're doing, I'd _highly_ suggest you go through a tutorial that explains these concepts in a structured way instead of throwing yourself at problems you might not be equipped for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all the genres in a dict, then pick from the appropriate list based on the key.

```py
import random
albums = {
    'rock' : ['Dark Side of the Moon - Pink Floyd'],
    'rap' : ['Igor - Tyler, the Creator'],
    'indie' : ['Currents - Tame Impala']
}
genre = input("What genre are you feeling?\n")
if genre in albums:
    print(random.choice(albums[genre]))
```